# GWT 2.8 compiler warnings

Tags: java, gwt, ant

When I switched from GWT 2.7 to 2.8 I started getting the following warnings. I am compiling from the command line using ant and Oracle Java 7. I do not receive any of these warnings when I switch back to GWT 2.7

```
                           [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]    Resolving java.lang.Runnable
 [java]       Found type 'java.lang.Runnable'
 [java]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]    Resolving java.util.Arrays
 [java]       Found type 'java.util.Arrays'
 [java]          Resolving method parallelPrefix
 [java]             Found type 'java.util.function.BinaryOperator'
 [java]                [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]                Found type 'java.util.function.BiFunction'
 [java]                   [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]          Resolving method setAll
 [java]             Found type 'java.util.function.IntFunction'
 [java]                [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]          Resolving method stream
 [java]             Found type 'java.util.stream.Stream'
 [java]                Resolving method collect
 [java]                   Found type 'java.util.stream.Collector'
 [java]                      Resolving method supplier
 [java]                         Found type 'java.util.function.Supplier'
 [java]                            [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]                      Resolving method accumulator
 [java]                         Found type 'java.util.function.BiConsumer'
 [java]                            [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]                Resolving method flatMapToDouble
 [java]                   Found type 'java.util.stream.DoubleStream'
 [java]                      Resolving method collect
 [java]                         Found type 'java.util.function.ObjDoubleConsumer'
 [java]                            [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
 [java]                      Resolving method flatMap
 [java]                         Found type
```

Answer (score 5):

`java.lang.FunctionalInterface` was added in Java 8, and GWT resolves annotations from the classpath, so, because the Java Runtime Emulation library was updated to Java 8, you'll have those warnings when using GWT 2.8 with a Java 7 VM.

Because Java 7 is EOL'd for some time already, it was deemed acceptable to have these warnings in this case. Independent from GWT, you're encouraged to move to Java 8.